# How to get the angular position of a the rotating object of a motor constraint in python scripting during animation play ? (Blender 2.78)

Tags: python, scripting, constraints

I have a simple scene with a motor and its shaft on which a spool is attached.
The animation works, the shaft is rotating and I can control its value from python using :

```
bpy.data.objects['Constraint.motor'].rigid_body_constraint.motor_ang_target_velocity = 0.5
```

It must be possible to get the actual rotation (angular position) of the shaft, but when I do :

```
bpy.data.objects['Spool'].rotation_euler
```

it only gives me the Euler angles at keyframe 0, but not the actual value as the animation is being played.
Is their a way to access this value ?

The final goal is to simulate a motor encoder for a robotics simulation.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Object's [matrix_world](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.matrix_world) is what you're after. Call [to_euler(...)](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.to_euler) to get the Euler angles.

`bpy.data.objects['Spool'].matrix_world.to_euler('XYZ')`